# In R how do I sample one non-zero element from each column of a matrix and then -1 from it

Tags: r, matrix, vector, sample

I have a matrix called MyMatrix:

```
a<-c(1,2,0)
b<-c(0,5,0)
c<-c(8,9,2)
d<-c(5,2,0)

MyMatrix<-cbind(a,b,c,d)

     a b c d
[1,] 1 0 8 5
[2,] 2 5 9 2
[3,] 0 0 2 0
```

From MyMatrix I would like to -1 from an element in every column, but only if the element is >0.

For example, the resulting matrix might be:

```
     a b c d
[1,] 0 0 8 5
[2,] 2 4 8 1
[3,] 0 0 2 0
```

How might I achieve this?

Comment: For random one element per column or all elements?

Comment: Just one random element per column (of all the non-zero elements in that column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
safeSample<-function(x) {if (length(x)==1) x else sample(x, 1)}
apply(MyMatrix, 2, 
      function(x) {
          ind<-safeSample(which(x>0)) 
          x[ind]<-x[ind]-1 
          x
      }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Update

As per the feedback, I previously misunderstood the objective, but I guess the following `apply` way should work

```
apply(
    MyMatrix,
    2,
    function(v) {
        k <- which(v > 0)
        idx <- sample(seq_along(k), 1)
        replace(v, k[idx], v[k[idx]] - 1)
    }
)
```

which gives

```
     a b c d
[1,] 0 0 6 5
[2,] 1 4 9 1
[3,] 0 0 2 0
```

---

We can do like this using `sample` to generate the random indices that should be subtracted by `1` if its entry is greater than `0`

```
idx <- cbind(
    sample(nrow(MyMatrix), ncol(MyMatrix), TRUE),
    1:ncol(MyMatrix)
)
MyMatrix[idx] <- MyMatrix[idx] - (MyMatrix[idx] > 0)
```

Comment: I think that with this solution some of the columns might not have an element changed (can't be sure whether the requirement is to have always an element per column changed).

Comment: @nicola Yes, you are right. I am not sure if I misunderstood OP's goal. Let me give it another shot.

Comment: This almost does it but as I think @nicola means too, what I was trying to do was first select all elements in each column that are >0  and then -1 from one of these elements in each column.

Comment: @locket See my update